# Redux form not managed by the application, with weird error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I m trying to put hands on the Redux Form modules, I m having troubles and I can't understand why I have that kind of weird errors.

My current problem is to display a SearchBar in a component that is called "Login" :

import React from 'react';
import SearchBar from './../../cmp/searchBar/searchBar';

```
export default class Login extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And here's the SearchBar component :

```
import React from 'react';
import {Field, reduxForm} from 'redux-form';
/**
 * The seach bar component class definition
 */
class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  /**
   * Render the searchBar component
   */
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <Field name="inputField" component="input" type="text"/>
        <button type="submit">Rechercher</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

/**
 * Decorate the form
 */
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'searchBar'
})(SearchBar);
```

And here's my root component managed by react-router :

```
// some other stuff here...
import {createStore, combineReducers} from 'redux';
import {reducer as formReducer} from 'redux-form';
const reducers = {
  form: formReducer
};
const reducer = combineReducers(reducers);
const store = createStore(reducer, window.devToolsExtension && window.devToolsExtension());

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={Home}>
        <Route path="login" component={Login}/>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The fact is that I can't see my component on the screen and I m simply having the following error in my browser console :

```
reduxForm.js:645 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'wrapped' of undefined
```

I m probably missing something somewhere ... I can't find where.

Any idea ?

**EDIT (partially resolved)** : It seems that on redux-form v6.x (because of webpack 2), there's an error and we have to make something (strange) like exporting an object containing the component :

```
import React from 'react';
import {Field, reduxForm} from 'redux-form';
/**
 * The seach bar component class definition
 */
class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  /**
   * Render the searchBar component
   */
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <Field name="inputField" component="input" type="text"/>
        <button type="submit">Rechercher</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

const sb = reduxForm({
  form: 'searchBar'
})(SearchBar);

export default {
  sb
};
```

And so :

```
<SearchBar.sb/>
```

No errors, but nothing displayed on the screen for now :(

EDIT : The problem was because of Redux form 6.x . I've downgraded and it works like a charm :D

Answer (score 1):

I did a little bit of research and I found following thread:

https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1010

Not sure if you are using webpack, but:

> To make it work with webpack 2, the workaround currentlyis to export
>   an object with a reference to the form component, instead of the form
>   component itself.

I actually always use following syntax and it works so far:

```
const SearchBarForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'searchBar'
})(SearchBar);
```

and then export `SearchBarForm`

Comment: I think this is what I m doing in the Decorator part of the SearchBar component, except that I don't use an intermediate variable. But thank you for the suggestion :)